# Read a parquet file in linux machine

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I tried to read parquet file in python.
I used parquet and json imports.
I used the below code as I'm not looking to use pandas.

```
with open("test.parquet") as fo:
    for row in parquet.DictReader(fo):
        print(json.dumps(row))
```

This seemed to have worked fine.
I wanted to implement the same in R so I tried using "reticulate", to use python functions in R.
I used the following code:

```
library(reticulate)
py <- import_builtins()
pq <- import("parquet")
js <- import("json")

with(py$open("test.parquet") %as% pq_file, {
for (val in pq$DictReader(pq_file)) {
print(js$dumps(val))}})
```

Since I'm just trying it, I try different things, and  I get different errors. For the above code, I got this.

```
Error in for (val in pq$DictReader(pq_file)) { : invalid for() loop sequence
```

I tried this too:

```
with(py$open("test.parquet") %as% pq_file, {
for (val in 1:4) {
print(js$dumps(pq$DictReader(pq_file)$keys()[val]))}})
```

and the error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I'm trying to use reticulate to read parquet file in R.
Or any other way to read parquet file in R. I'm not looking to use pandas at all. I also tried pyarrow, but it needs pandas to interfere

If I can use python's with Context or For loop in R(I don't think that's feasible but just in case), I think that'll do it.
If anyone has any knowledge about it. Let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Spark, and just want to read a parquet file in R by any means without using Pandas, you can read it easily using the *sparklyr* package and the *spark_read_parquet* function.

Here is a reference on its use: https://spark.rstudio.com/reference/spark_read_parquet/

The following works fine for me (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
library(sparklyr)

spark_conn <- spark_connect(master = "local")

data_frame <- collect(spark_read_parquet(spark_conn, "my_parquet", "~/data/my_parquet.parquet"))

spark_disconnect(spark_conn)
```

For this to work, be sure to have both *sparklyr* and *dplyr* installed

```
install.packages(dplyr)
install.packages(sparklyr)
```

If you need to configure Spark, there is an easy interface using `spark_install()` once you loaded *sparklyr* (provided that you use Java 8). You can easily downgrade Java by using

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo update-alternatives --config java ==> select the option to use Java 8
```

Comment: This is helpful, I did come across this some time back. But I'm not looking to use `Sparklyr` for the sole purpose to read the file, I'm looking for something like _Pandas in Python_. I'm waiting for `rarrow` to release.